# Is there a way I can use a for loop to only take a certain section of a list with each loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know my question may seem very vague I'm just trying to finish an assignment and I am so very confused ;-;. I am trying to use a for loop to only take out five numbers in a list at a time in a different function. Heres the program I have so far:

```
def main():
    #Create empty dictionary
    gradebook = {}
    #Prompt user to enter course
    course_name = input('Enter a course name ==> ')
    #Set 'course_count' to 0
    course_count = 0
    #Create empty list
    list1 = []
    while course_name != '':
        #Prompt user to enter another course or hit enter to quit
        course_name = input('Enter another course name or press enter to end ==> ')
        #Add 1 to 'course_count' for every loop
        course_count += 1
    #Create list for every course
    for count in range(course_count):
        for count in range(5):
            #Randomly pick a number from 70 to 100
            grades = random.randint(70,100)
            #Append these values to 'list1'
            list1.append(grades)
    #I was using this to see the list that was created
    print(list1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is my discord username for anyone who would be ok with helping me any further as well:ButternutSquash#1825. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/how-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks